# AngularJS, ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

is there anyone who knows how to disable this white space after rows inside grid ?

I would like it to match number of rows and make it sticked.

No white space needed there.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/qGmtv3IbS5kXIAWQGaSH?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this issue here : https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1735

I think that at the moment, your have to change the height of your grid dynamically depending on the number of data rows.
Check this link for examples.